# Should I save ints in SQLite Database?

Tags: android

I have optional data that can be downloaded from the app.. of course I need to check in every app start which optional data has been downloaded.. The optional data is numbered from 1 to 114..   I was wondering where to store this info?
Should I save it in SharedSettings? or in my sqlite database? Is database access considered a heavy thing for the app?
Thanks.

Comment: database access is fairly quick and lightweight.  using SharedPreferences will make for an easy implementation but may not be as flexible or ideal.